# Perl scripts in IIS 6 fail with HTTP 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: perl, awstats

I've download latest ActivePerl and configured Web Site Extensions along with script mappings with .pl extension for target site in IIS 6.

Also did the exact same in IIS 7.5 and it worked.

The script I'm trying to execute is very simple "Hello World" first and then configure AWStats, which I'm also able to do in IIS 7.5 with no issues..

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction..

Thanks
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for IIS seems to indicate that for some time there have been some headaches with IIS and that some manual configuration can be needed.

They made this tool to help with that:

http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/bin/ap-iis-config.html

Have you tried using this? Perhaps it can help you.

Here is a relevant blog post about it:

http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/06/setting-iis-activeperl

Comment: I did the above right form the start, but it didn't help. Seems like we need to tweak the Local Group Policy settings:  Local Security Policy > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Add IIS_WPG group to: 
1. Adjust memory quotas for a process 
2. Replace a process-level token

http://www.beamartyr.net/articles/iisperl.html